# Rxkotlin - How to zip more than three observables with zip operator

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I need to zip more than 3 observables with zip operator in rxkotlin, but when i try to zip more than 3 it shows me compile time error.
**Example**

```
 Observables.zip(Observable.just(someFun(0),Observable.just(someFun(1),Observable.just(someFun(2),Observable.just(someFun(3))
```

Is there we can zip more than 3 observable ?
Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `zip`ping more than three `Observable`s? RxKotlin has a `zip` function up until six sources.
So the answer is: yes, you can zip more than 3 observables.